# Inkscape Missing part on my ellipse on the svg file but not on the pdf file

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I am drawing circles and ellipses and some of them miss a part when I change them into an arc or pie part (maybe not the right name, my computer is in French and it's called camembert). But not systematically (or I miss the pattern).

Another strange thing is that when I convert my file into a pdf, the arc or pie is complete.

This picture is a screenshot of my svg file in Inkscape when a part is missing.
[image: screenshot of my svg file when incomplete]

This one is the same file, same picture but when I move a bit the handle (it's complete).
[image: screenshot of my svg file when complete]

And finally this one is the screenshot of the pdf file of the first (incomplete) picture.
[image: screenshot of my pdf file. The figure is complete while its svg conterpart is not]

(sorry for the disproportionate pictures)

EDIT : I did some more tests

- when the circle/ellipse is by default : no issue, no missing part.
- when the circle/ellipse has been turned horizontally OR vertically (not both) a missing part may appears around the width and height handles
- when the circle/ellipse has been turned horizontally AND vertically : no issue, no missing part

EDIT BIS : Here is the link to the file https://svgshare.com/i/uvJ.svg. Very strange thing, on the computer, there's no missing part.
I also opened it on another computer (Inkscape 0.92.5 (2060ec1f9f, 2020-04-08)) and I don't have the problem anymore.

I use Debian GNU/Linux 11 and Inkscape 1.0.2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15) Pango version: 1.46.2

Comment: Hi. I can't reproduce this problem. If you want, you can share the SVG at SVGshare.com - and share the link here. I can take a look at it.  Also which version of Inkscape are you using?

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks. I'll edit the post to add those information. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I can't see anything wrong with the SVG. I'm using 1.2.2 which is the most recent stable version. Try updating Inkscape

Comment: Hi, ok thank you

Comment: Now my issue is how to install the 1.2.2 version with apt (I need it for texText extension)

Comment: Sorry but installation of software is off-topic here. Perhaps you could ask on [Unix&Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour#:~:text=Unix%20%26%20Linux%20Stack%20Exchange%20is%20a%20question,answers%20to%20every%20question%20about%20Unix%20or%20Linux.)

Comment: I know. Sorry I just wanted to express what my next step is. I wasn't asking for help.
Should I remove my previous comment ? (and this one ?)

Comment: No. It's fine. You don't have to remove comments.